# Check for acceptance of type, rather than value, with isDefinedAt

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a case where I want use `isDefinedAt` to check if a partial function accepts a type, rather than a specific value.

```
val test: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = { 
  case y: Int => ???
  case ComplexThing(x, y, z) => ??? 
}
```

Here you could do something like `test isDefinedAt 1` to check for acceptance of that value, however, what I really want to do is check for acceptance of all `Int`s (more specifically, in my case the type I want to check is awkward to initialize (it has a lot of dependencies), so I would really like to avoid creating an instance if possible - for the moment I'm just using `null`s, which feels ugly). Unfortunately, there is no `test.isDefinedAt[Int]`.

I'm not worried about it only accepting some instances of that type - I would just like to know if it's completely impossible that type is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that this simply isn't possible - there are other ways to do this (as in [wingedsubmariner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865720/722121)), but that requires either duplicating the information (which renders it pointless, as the reason for doing this was to avoid that), or changing not to use partial functions (which is dictated by an outside API).

The best solution is just to use `null`s to fill the dependencies to create instances to check with. It's ugly, and has it's own issues, but it appears to be the best possible without substantial change.

```
test.isDefinedAt(ComplexThing(null, null, null))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make `PartialFunction` do this. In fact, because of type erasure, it can be difficult to operate on types at runtime. If you want to be able to verify types at compile-time you can use typeclasses instead:

```
class AllowType[-T] {
  def allowed = true
}

object AllowType {
  implicit object DontAllowAnyType extends AllowType[Any] {
    override def allowed = false
  }
}

implicit object AllowInt extends AllowType[Int]
implicit object AllowString extends AllowType[String]

def isTypeAllowed[T](implicit at: AllowType[T]) = at.allowed

isTypeAllowed[Int] // true
isTypeAllowed[Double] // false
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this would then require duplicating all of the information about what the `PartialFunction` accepts?

Comment: Yes, though you could do away with the `PartialFunction` entirely and add another method to the typeclass that does the computation as well.

Comment: +1, this might be a solution for some people, but due to my circumstances, it doesn't fit my needs (the use of the PartialFunction is dictated by an outside API, and the goal was to test the PartialFunction, so duplicating the information would render it pointless). I think the answer for me is just that it isn't possible in the way I'd like.